# How can I remove the pace loading page from the website HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pace

How can I remove the pace loading page from the website HTML page?

css pace file:

```
.pace {
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  pointer-events: none;

  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

  -webkit-perspective: 12rem;
  -moz-perspective: 12rem;
  -ms-perspective: 12rem;
  -o-perspective: 12rem;
  perspective: 12rem;

  z-index: 2000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 6rem;
  width: 6rem;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.pace .pace-activity {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
  top: 35px;
  right: 35px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 2px transparent;
  border-top-color: #0aa699;
  border-left-color: #0aa699;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-animation: pace-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: pace-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: pace-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -o-animation: pace-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  animation: pace-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
}

.pace.pace-inactive .pace-activity {
  display: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pace-spinner {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes pace-spinner {
  0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes pace-spinner {
  0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes pace-spinner {
  0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes pace-spinner {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

pace js file :

```
/*! pace 0.4.15 */
(function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O=[].slice,P={}.hasOwnProperty,Q=function(a,b){function c(){this.constructor=a}for(var d in b)P.call(b,d)&&(a[d]=b[d]);return c.prototype=b.prototype,a.prototype=new c,a.__super__=b.prototype,a},R=[].indexOf||function(a){for(var b=0,c=this.length;c>b;b++)if(b in this&&this[b]===a)return b;return-1};s={catchupTime:500,initialRate:.03,minTime:500,ghostTime:250,maxProgressPerFrame:10,easeFactor:1.25,startOnPageLoad:!0,restartOnPushState:!0,restartOnRequestAfter:500,target:"body",elements:{checkInterval:100,selectors:["body"]},eventLag:{minSamples:10,sampleCount:3,lagThreshold:3},ajax:{trackMethods:["GET"],trackWebSockets:!1}},z=function(){var a;return null!=(a="undefined"!=typeof performance&&null!==performance?"function"==typeof performance.now?performance.now():void 0:void 0)?a:+new Date},B=window.requestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame,r=window.cancelAnimationFrame||window.mozCancelAnimationFrame,null==B&&(B=function(a){return setTimeout(a,50)},r=function(a){return clearTimeout(a)}),D=function(a){var b,c;return b=z(),c=function(){var d;return d=z()-b,b=z(),a(d,function(){return B(c)})},c()},C=function(){var a,b,c;return c=arguments[0],b=arguments[1],a=3<=arguments.length?O.call(arguments,2):[],"function"==typeof c[b]?c[b].apply(c,a):c[b]},t=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g;for(b=arguments[0],d=2<=arguments.length?O.call(arguments,1):[],f=0,g=d.length;g>f;f++)if(c=d[f])for(a in c)P.call(c,a)&&(e=c[a],null!=b[a]&&"object"==typeof b[a]&&null!=e&&"object"==typeof e?t(b[a],e):b[a]=e);return b},o=function(a){var b,c,d,e,f;for(c=b=0,e=0,f=a.length;f>e;e++)d=a[e],c+=Math.abs(d),b++;return c/b},v=function(a,b){var c,d,e;if(null==a&&(a="options"),null==b&&(b=!0),e=document.querySelector("[data-pace-"+a+"]")){if(c=e.getAttribute("data-pace-"+a),!b)return c;try{return JSON.parse(c)}catch(f){return d=f,"undefined"!=typeof console&&null!==console?console.error("Error parsing inline pace options",d):void 0}}},null==window.Pace&&(window.Pace={}),A=Pace.options=t(s,window.paceOptions,v()),h=function(a){function b(){return M=b.__super__.constructor.apply(this,arguments)}return Q(b,a),b}(Error),b=function(){function a(){this.progress=0}return a.prototype.getElement=function(){var a;if(null==this.el){if(a=document.querySelector(A.target),!a)throw new h;this.el=document.createElement("div"),this.el.className="pace pace-active",document.body.className=document.body.className.replace("pace-done",""),document.body.className+=" pace-running",this.el.innerHTML='<div class="pace-progress">\n  <div class="pace-progress-inner"></div>\n</div>\n<div class="pace-activity"></div>',null!=a.firstChild?a.insertBefore(this.el,a.firstChild):a.appendChild(this.el)}return this.el},a.prototype.finish=function(){var a;return a=this.getElement(),a.className=a.className.replace("pace-active",""),a.className+=" pace-inactive",document.body.className=document.body.className.replace("pace-running",""),document.body.className+=" pace-done"},a.prototype.update=function(a){return this.progress=a,this.render()},a.prototype.destroy=function(){try{this.getElement().parentNode.removeChild(this.getElement())}catch(a){h=a}return this.el=void 0},a.prototype.render=function(){var a,b;return null==document.querySelector(A.target)?!1:(a=this.getElement(),a.children[0].style.width=""+this.progress+"%",(!this.lastRenderedProgress||0|(this.lastRenderedProgress|0!==this.progress))&&(a.children[0].setAttribute("data-progress-text",""+(0|this.progress)+"%"),this.progress>=100?b="99":(b=this.progress<10?"0":"",b+=0|this.progress),a.children[0].setAttribute("data-progress",""+b)),this.lastRenderedProgress=this.progress)},a.prototype.done=function(){return this.progress>=100},a}(),g=function(){function a(){this.bindings={}}return a.prototype.trigger=function(a,b){var c,d,e,f,g;if(null!=this.bindings[a]){for(f=this.bindings[a],g=[],d=0,e=f.length;e>d;d++)c=f[d],g.push(c.call(this,b));return g}},a.prototype.on=function(a,b){var c;return null==(c=this.bindings)[a]&&(c[a]=[]),this.bindings[a].push(b)},a}(),J=window.XMLHttpRequest,I=window.XDomainRequest,H=window.WebSocket,u=function(a,b){var c,d,e,f;f=[];for(d in b.prototype)try{e=b.prototype[d],null==a[d]&&"function"!=typeof e?f.push(a[d]=e):f.push(void 0)}catch(g){c=g}return f},i=function(a){function b(){var a,c=this;b.__super__.constructor.apply(this,arguments),a=function(a){var b;return b=a.open,a.open=function(d,e){var f;return f=(null!=d?d:"GET").toUpperCase(),R.call(A.ajax.trackMethods,f)>=0&&c.trigger("request",{type:d,url:e,request:a}),b.apply(a,arguments)}},window.XMLHttpRequest=function(b){var c;return c=new J(b),a(c),c},u(window.XMLHttpRequest,J),null!=I&&(window.XDomainRequest=function(){var b;return b=new I,a(b),b},u(window.XDomainRequest,I)),null!=H&&A.ajax.trackWebSockets&&(window.WebSocket=function(a,b){var d;return d=new H(a,b),c.trigger("request",{type:"socket",url:a,protocols:b,request:d}),d},u(window.WebSocket,H))}return Q(b,a),b}(g),K=null,w=function(){return null==K&&(K=new i),K},A.restartOnRequestAfter!==!1&&w().on("request",function(b){var c,d,e;return e=b.type,d=b.request,Pace.running?void 0:(c=arguments,setTimeout(function(){var b,f,g,h,i,j,k;if(f="socket"===e?d.readyState<2:0<(i=d.readyState)&&4>i){for(Pace.restart(),j=Pace.sources,k=[],g=0,h=j.length;h>g;g++){if(b=j[g],b instanceof a){b.watch.apply(b,c);break}k.push(void 0)}return k}},A.restartOnRequestAfter))}),a=function(){function a(){var a=this;this.elements=[],w().on("request",function(){return a.watch.apply(a,arguments)})}return a.prototype.watch=function(a){var b,c,d;return d=a.type,b=a.request,c="socket"===d?new l(b):new m(b),this.elements.push(c)},a}(),m=function(){function a(a){var b,c,d,e,f,g,h=this;if(this.progress=0,null!=window.ProgressEvent)for(c=null,a.addEventListener("progress",function(a){return h.progress=a.lengthComputable?100*a.loaded/a.total:h.progress+(100-h.progress)/2}),g=["load","abort","timeout","error"],d=0,e=g.length;e>d;d++)b=g[d],a.addEventListener(b,function(){return h.progress=100});else f=a.onreadystatechange,a.onreadystatechange=function(){var b;return 0===(b=a.readyState)||4===b?h.progress=100:3===a.readyState&&(h.progress=50),"function"==typeof f?f.apply(null,arguments):void 0}}return a}(),l=function(){function a(a){var b,c,d,e,f=this;for(this.progress=0,e=["error","open"],c=0,d=e.length;d>c;c++)b=e[c],a.addEventListener(b,function(){return f.progress=100})}return a}(),d=function(){function a(a){var b,c,d,f;for(null==a&&(a={}),this.elements=[],null==a.selectors&&(a.selectors=[]),f=a.selectors,c=0,d=f.length;d>c;c++)b=f[c],this.elements.push(new e(b))}return a}(),e=function(){function a(a){this.selector=a,this.progress=0,this.check()}return a.prototype.check=function(){var a=this;return document.querySelector(this.selector)?this.done():setTimeout(function(){return a.check()},A.elements.checkInterval)},a.prototype.done=function(){return this.progress=100},a}(),c=function(){function a(){var a,b,c=this;this.progress=null!=(b=this.states[document.readyState])?b:100,a=document.onreadystatechange,document.onreadystatechange=function(){return null!=c.states[document.readyState]&&(c.progress=c.states[document.readyState]),"function"==typeof a?a.apply(null,arguments):void 0}}return a.prototype.states={loading:0,interactive:50,complete:100},a}(),f=function(){function a(){var a,b,c,d,e,f=this;this.progress=0,a=0,e=[],d=0,c=z(),b=setInterval(function(){var g;return g=z()-c-50,c=z(),e.push(g),e.length>A.eventLag.sampleCount&&e.shift(),a=o(e),++d>=A.eventLag.minSamples&&a<A.eventLag.lagThreshold?(f.progress=100,clearInterval(b)):f.progress=100*(3/(a+3))},50)}return a}(),k=function(){function a(a){this.source=a,this.last=this.sinceLastUpdate=0,this.rate=A.initialRate,this.catchup=0,this.progress=this.lastProgress=0,null!=this.source&&(this.progress=C(this.source,"progress"))}return a.prototype.tick=function(a,b){var c;return null==b&&(b=C(this.source,"progress")),b>=100&&(this.done=!0),b===this.last?this.sinceLastUpdate+=a:(this.sinceLastUpdate&&(this.rate=(b-this.last)/this.sinceLastUpdate),this.catchup=(b-this.progress)/A.catchupTime,this.sinceLastUpdate=0,this.last=b),b>this.progress&&(this.progress+=this.catchup*a),c=1-Math.pow(this.progress/100,A.easeFactor),this.progress+=c*this.rate*a,this.progress=Math.min(this.lastProgress+A.maxProgressPerFrame,this.progress),this.progress=Math.max(0,this.progress),this.progress=Math.min(100,this.progress),this.lastProgress=this.progress,this.progress},a}(),F=null,E=null,p=null,G=null,n=null,q=null,Pace.running=!1,x=function(){return A.restartOnPushState?Pace.restart():void 0},null!=window.history.pushState&&(L=window.history.pushState,window.history.pushState=function(){return x(),L.apply(window.history,arguments)}),null!=window.history.replaceState&&(N=window.history.replaceState,window.history.replaceState=function(){return x(),N.apply(window.history,arguments)}),j={ajax:a,elements:d,document:c,eventLag:f},(y=function(){var a,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,l;for(Pace.sources=F=[],h=["ajax","elements","document","eventLag"],d=0,f=h.length;f>d;d++)c=h[d],A[c]!==!1&&F.push(new j[c](A[c]));for(l=null!=(i=A.extraSources)?i:[],e=0,g=l.length;g>e;e++)a=l[e],F.push(new a(A));return Pace.bar=p=new b,E=[],G=new k})(),Pace.stop=function(){return Pace.running=!1,p.destroy(),q=!0,null!=n&&("function"==typeof r&&r(n),n=null),y()},Pace.restart=function(){return Pace.stop(),Pace.start()},Pace.go=function(){return Pace.running=!0,p.render(),q=!1,n=D(function(a,b){var c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,l,m,n,o,r,s,t,u,v,w;for(j=100-p.progress,d=r=0,e=!0,h=s=0,u=F.length;u>s;h=++s)for(n=F[h],m=null!=E[h]?E[h]:E[h]=[],g=null!=(w=n.elements)?w:[n],i=t=0,v=g.length;v>t;i=++t)f=g[i],l=null!=m[i]?m[i]:m[i]=new k(f),e&=l.done,l.done||(d++,r+=l.tick(a));return c=r/d,p.update(G.tick(a,c)),o=z(),p.done()||e||q?(p.update(100),setTimeout(function(){return p.finish(),Pace.running=!1},Math.max(A.ghostTime,Math.min(A.minTime,z()-o)))):b()})},Pace.start=function(a){t(A,a),Pace.running=!0;try{p.render()}catch(b){h=b}return document.querySelector(".pace")?Pace.go():setTimeout(Pace.start,50)},"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(function(){return Pace}):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=Pace:A.startOnPageLoad&&Pace.start()}).call(this);
```

these two css and js files are put as a link in my php file, when removing them, a blank page is coming, everything in the html is disappeared. I don't know how can I get rid of that pace loading feature.[image]

Comment: '
  <link href="assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        media="screen" />

  <script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
`

css and js files are inserted like this in the php index file...

Comment: If removing the CSS and JS sets the page's content to be hidden, that means there is something in your code that is hiding it.

Comment: yes it's hiding the page's content.
Like what?! @imvain2

Comment: Its something in your CSS. I would try learning your browser's inspect element tool and find the root elements to see how they are hidden.